# How the third excluded principle in Aristotle's Metaphysics should be understood?

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle

I'm having trouble understanding Aristotle's argument for the Third Excluded Principle (from [Book 4, part 7](https://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/metaphysics.4.iv.html)). What I mean, I try to read the two paragraphs of that part but what I can't figure out is: how is this compatible with the notion that there is an intermediate state between childhood and adulthood? If someone is in the intermediate state, let's say is a teenager, then in some sense is a child and in some sense is an adult. It's impossible to affirm or deny completely that he is a child or an adult.

But he doesn't give to understand that

> so that it will be possible for a man to say what is neither true nor untrue, and there will be a middle between that which is and that which is not, so that there will also be a kind of change intermediate between generation and destruction.-Again, in all classes in which the negation of an attribute involves the assertion of its contrary, even in these there will be an intermediate; for instance, in the sphere of numbers there will be number which is neither odd nor not-odd. But **this is impossible**, as is obvious from the definition.

Does this mean that, for Aristotle, there's one single ‘magic moment’ in your life that you become adult and you are no more a child?

EDIT: I should clarify a little more my question. He continues:

> Again, the process will go on ad infinitum, and the number of realities will be not only half as great again, but even greater. For again it will be possible to deny this intermediate with reference both to its assertion and to its negation, and **this new term will be some definite thing**; for its essence is something different.-Again, when a man, on being asked whether a thing is white, says 'no', he has denied nothing except that it is; and its not being is a negation.

So, as I understand, in my case I should say that ‘he/she is a teenager, neither a child nor an adult’. But, the previous question somehow still is not answered. Because in that case, what happens between a child and a teenager? Does he think the life from childhood to adulthood as a ‘concatenation of discrete periods’ rather than like a continuum?

Comment: The key-point is "the negation of an attribute that involves it's contrary":: odd-even.

Comment: Child and adult are not negations of each other. What Aristotle has in mind is that one can always assert that someone is a child or a non-child, without any middle. Some modern philosophers disagree even with that when it comes to [vague predicates](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vagueness/) like "is a child"

Comment: @Conifold So, he saw life a something ‘discrete’? I mean, an early teenager is a child or not? If my point can be understood, how does he think ‘that’ crucial moment would come, if is not a change with a derivative d/dt equal to infinity?

Comment: Aristotle appears to deal there only with crisp predicates with sharp boundaries and no borderline cases, like "minor". There is a modern position called [epistemicism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sorites-paradox/#EpisTheo) that eliminates vague predicates by asserting that they too have sharp boundaries, but those are unknown to us precisely and may depend on context.  An early teenager is a child, a 17 year old is either a child or not, but we may not know which. In some contexts, (s)he may be a child, in other contexts not, depending, say on the voting age or the age of consent.

Comment: @Conifold Now it's much clearer, thanks.

Comment: See *Met*, 1011b23:"But on the other hand there cannot be an intermediate between contradictories, but of one subject we must either affirm or deny any one predicate. This is clear, in the first place, if we define what the true and the false are. To say of
what is that it is not, or of what is not that it is, is false, while to say of what is
that it is, and of what is not that it is not, is true[...] Again, either the intermediate
between the contradictories will be so in the way in which grey is between black
and white, or as that which is neither man nor horse is between man and horse.

Comment: So, there are "intermediate" like the case white-grey-blak but there are no intermediate between contradictory pairs: white/not-white, odd/not-odd (i.e. even).